# How to mount Rootfs on sama5d27-som1-ek board using NFS

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, nfs, rootfs

i am trying to mount rootfs on board using NFS

my NFS export file

```
/home/user/demo/rootfs  192.168.0.200(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

my kernel arguments are

```
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rootfstype=nfs ip=192.168.0.102 rw nfsroot=192.168.0.200:/home/user/demo/rootfs,4.1
```

when i boot my board it shows following error

```
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, hwaddr=54:10:ec:a9:81:79, ipaddr=192.168.0.100, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255
     host=192.168.0.100, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
     bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=192.168.0.100, rootpath=
ALSA device list:
  No soundcards found.
atmel_usart_serial atmel_usart_serial.0.auto: using dma0chan5 for rx DMA transfers
atmel_usart_serial atmel_usart_serial.0.auto: using dma0chan6 for tx DMA transfers
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS
```

i dont know whats is wrong but i am not able mount rootfs,anyone have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Enable more debugging via kernel command line and, possible, kernel configuration. At least be sure you have `ignore_loglevel initcall_debug` set. Besides that it's good to have early console enabled (see documentation for `earlycon` kernel command line parameter).

Comment: Your description is sparse and incomplete.  Has the kernel been configured/built with the salient requisite capabilities?  Have you tested that the target NFS filesystem is mountable?  Your kernel log seems edited and has insufficient content.  The <nfs-options> field in the `nfsroot=` parameter in the kernel command line looks suspicious.  The `ip=` parameter in the kernel command line is incomplete, i.e. the ("*required* for NFS root") <server-ip> field is missing from this parameter.  Study **Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt**

Comment: Ok i will study.and I have tested nfs server using Windows nfs client i am able to access file on my windows system .

Comment: According to your log you configured the device IP 192.168.0.100, the same as the server address. Fix that and retry.

Comment: @LucaCeresoli i ahve change it but can you suggest me proper bootargs to set